# CSS display: flex - required prefixes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I changed the way of display input-groups in Twitter Bootstrap 3.2 from `display: table` to `display: flex`
but I'm not sure which CSS prefixes are necessary to support older browsers.

My current code:

```
.form-group.input-group{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    -moz-align-items: stretch;
    -ms-align-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
}
.form-group.input-group > *:not( .input-group-addon){    
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -moz-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.input-group-addon{
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
    -moz-flex: 1 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Do I need to use all of those prefixes or some of them are useless?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you don't need to specify `*` when combining the `>` selector with `:not()`, you can simply `.form-... > :not(...)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com) for this. Here is a direct link to browser support for `flexbox`: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

[image: Screenshot of Can I Use results]

From this we can see that:

- IE10 requires the `-ms-` prefix and only supports the 2012 syntax (as mentioned in the *Notes* section on the page).
- Safari, iOS Safari and older versions of Android Browser require the `-webkit-` prefix.
- This does not work at all on IE9 or lower, or Opera Mini.

We can also determine that for IE11 and more recent versions of Firefox, Chrome and Opera, the `-ms-`, `-moz-` and `-webkit-` prefixes *could* be dropped.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer). It's available for a wide range of tools. And you must only write pure CSS ;)

As an example you can prefixing your css with the CLI. On your **bootstrap.css** you write valid CSS based on the specs:

```
.form-group.input-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.form-group.input-group > *:not( .input-group-addon) {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.input-group-addon {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

And prefixing it with

```
sudo npm install --global autoprefixer
autoprefixer bootstrap.css
```

You can test the code on the [Autoprefixer Playground](http://simevidas.jsbin.com/gufoko/quiet) too

Ciao
Ralf